# Checkout "Return to Shipping Method" link

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout

I'd like to add a "Return to Shipping Method" link, before "Place Order" button in checkout page.

How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below file path and update code for "Return to Shipping Method" link in Checkout page.

Below is the core vendor file path you can overwrite file as per your theme.

**File path:**

> magento/vendor/magento/module-offline-payments/view/frontend/web/template/payment/checkmo.html

```
<div class="payment-method" data-bind="css: {'_active': (getCode() == isChecked())}">
    <div class="payment-method-title field choice">
        <input type="radio"
               name="payment[method]"
               class="radio"
               data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode()}, value: getCode(), checked: isChecked, click: selectPaymentMethod, visible: isRadioButtonVisible()"/>
        <label data-bind="attr: {'for': getCode()}" class="label"><span data-bind="text: getTitle()"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="payment-method-content">
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('messages') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
        <div class="payment-method-billing-address">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion(getBillingAddressFormName()) -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
        <!-- ko if: getMailingAddress() || getPayableTo() -->
        <dl class="items check payable">
            <!-- ko if: getPayableTo() -->
            <dt class="title"><!-- ko i18n: 'Make Check payable to:' --><!-- /ko --></dt>
            <dd class="content"><!-- ko text: getPayableTo() --><!-- /ko --></dd>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko if: getMailingAddress() -->
            <dt class="title"><!-- ko i18n: 'Send Check to:' --><!-- /ko --></dt>
            <dd class="content">
                <address class="checkmo mailing address" data-bind="html: getMailingAddress()"></address>
            </dd>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </dl>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <div class="checkout-agreements-block">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('before-place-order') -->
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
        <div class="actions-toolbar">

            <a data-bind="attr: {'href':getBaseUrl()}">Return to Shipping Method</a>

            <div class="primary">
                <button class="action primary checkout"
                        type="submit"
                        data-bind="
                        click: placeOrder,
                        attr: {title: $t('Place Order')},
                        css: {disabled: !isPlaceOrderActionAllowed()},
                        enable: (getCode() == isChecked())
                        "
                        disabled>
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Place Order'"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**File path:**

> magento/vendor/magento/module-offline-payments/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/checkmo-method.js

```
define([
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default',
    'mage/url'
], function (Component, mageurl) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Magento_OfflinePayments/payment/checkmo'
        },

        /**
         * Returns send check to info.
         *
         * @return {*}
         */
        getMailingAddress: function () {
            return window.checkoutConfig.payment.checkmo.mailingAddress;
        },

        /**
         * Returns payable to info.
         *
         * @return {*}
         */
        getPayableTo: function () {
            return window.checkoutConfig.payment.checkmo.payableTo;
        },

        getBaseUrl: function() {
            return mageurl.build('checkout/#shipping');
        }
    });
});
```

Let me know if any query.

Hope it help!